# path.centroid error: path is undefined

Tags: d3.js

I´still working on my project.
I try to add some circles to my map from a geojson file with the circles add the center of the paths.
My Webinspektor says path is undefined :-( I think he is right but I can´t figure out why.
Thank you for your helping.

Here is the   code:

```
overlayBeschaeftigte.afterAdd = function () {
                    var div = d3.selectAll("#" + overlayBeschaeftigte.div.id);
                        //get the vector layer div element

                    div.selectAll("svg").remove();                  //remove the existing svg element and create a new one

                    var svg = div.append("svg");

                    var group = svg.append("g");
                    var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(collection);

                    var path = d3.geo.path()
                        .projection(project);

                    var feature  = group.selectAll("path")
                        .data(collection.features)
                        .enter()
                        .append("path")
                    group.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(collection.features)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr('cx', function(d) {
                             var x = path.centroid(d)[0];
                             return x;

                        })
                        .attr('cy', function(d) {
                             var y = path.centroid(d)[1];
                             return y;
                        })
                        .attr('r', 15)
                        .style("fill", "yellow")
                        .style("opacity", 0.75) 
                }
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `path`?

Comment: So I have added the missing code in my original question.

Comment: [`path.centroid()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-path_centroid) is actually a function that takes the feature you want to compute the center of.

Comment: I changed my code for the cx and cy attribute to .attr('cx', function(d){
        return  path.centroid(d)[0]; but there are still no circles
       })
       .attr('cy', function(d){
        return  path.centroid(d)[1];
       })

Comment: Can you show us the complete code please?

Comment: Here is the whole code, it is an openlayers map with diefferent d3 Layers and more than one problem in ist :-(

Comment: Ok, could you maybe narrow it down to a small example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I hope this is better

Comment: You need to bind some data to the circles, similar to how you're doing it for the paths.

Comment: I tried around but nothing changes:-( I thought binding data was done by .data(collection.features)?

Comment: Ok, you keep changing the code that you post. In the current version, you need to return the value.

Comment: Oh sorry yes i changed it. I have changed i again with an return but there are still no circles

Comment: Could you please post a piece of code that allows to reproduce the problem (i.e. is complete)?

Comment: You want a piece of the json? or the whole code?

Comment: At the moment I can only guess. If I could actually try it would be much better.

Comment: Hello Lars Kotthoff, thank you for your helping, I sleep a night and now with all your answers I have the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Could you add it as an answer please for future reference?